# Is it possible to avoid executing make and make install with sudo?

Tags: permissions, make, makefile

Whenever it is possible, I try to use applications, libraries and plugins delivered through official Ubuntu APT.
However, sometimes I try to compile something, like `resynthesizer` plugin for GIMP. In many cases compilation requires me to execute `sudo make` and `sudo make install`. Without that, scripts fails, because they tries to copy files to folders that root has permission.

Since I am not the author of the program, I'm really afraid to do so (to execute such scripts as superuser). I am afraid that it will break the system. Is it possible to safely compile programs without using `sudo`?

Comment: You never need `sudo make` ;-) You may need `sudo make install` if the script install to system directories. But you can update Makefile and install locally.

Comment: You should always do a `make` first (no sudo required) and IF the code compiles cleanly, then do `sudo make install`. Any code, even from a reliable source, can break a system, but usually recovery is possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's always possible to *compile* software "locally" under your own home directory - how easy it is to install and run locally depends on the software's developers.

For opensource software that uses the familiar `automake` recipe of

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

the `configure` script should normally provide a `--prefix` option that sets the root of the installation path - for example

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
```

will cause generated binary files to be installed to the invoking user's `~/bin`, libraries to `~/lib`, configuration files to `~/etc` and so on. The directories will be created automatically if the do not already exist.

In the particular case of the [gimp resynthesizer plugin](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer) however, the `make install` step apparently still tries to install a couple of files to `$(GIMP_LIBDIR)/plug-ins`, where `GIMP_LIBDIR = /usr/lib/gimp/2.0` is hardcoded instead of derived from the `--prefix` value.

This may be an oversight by the software's maintainers, or may be for compatibility with GIMP itself. However you can overcome it by modifying the recipe as follows:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make GIMP_LIBDIR=$HOME/lib/gimp/2.0/ install
```

which should result in the following plug-in directory structure:

```
$ find ~/lib -newermt yesterday
/home/username/lib
/home/username/lib/gimp
/home/username/lib/gimp/2.0
/home/username/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins
/home/username/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/plugin-map-style.py
/home/username/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/plugin-heal-transparency.py
/home/username/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/plugin-resynth-enlarge.py
/home/username/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/plugin-render-texture.py
/home/username/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/resynthesizer
/home/username/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/resynthesizer_gui
/home/username/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/plugin-resynth-sharpen.py
/home/username/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/plugin-uncrop.py
/home/username/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/plugin-heal-selection.py
/home/username/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/plugin-resynth-fill-pattern.py
```